# How do I add sockets to an item?

Tags: diablo-iii

According to [this site](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/), the Jeweler can, besides removing and combining gems, also add new sockets to existing items.

I just acquired the Jeweler, but I can see no such option in his menus.

Do I have to upgrade him to a certain level to unlock the skill?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Diablo III Base Game

According to [Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149145075#8), the Artisan cannot add sockets, and the game guide is erroneous (to be updated in the future):

> **Artisans cannot add sockets to items.** That information about the
> jeweler in the game guide of our website is erroneous and we're in the
> process of updating it.
>
> Socketing was a feature that was in the game very early on, but
> ultimately it didn't end up enhancing the play experience as we had
> hoped.

Comment: how lame. gems are really powerful in this game. :P

Comment: will probably come in one of the expansions :))

Comment: This answer is now, semi correct as Adeese states down below.

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to add a socket to an item using vanilla Diablo 3.

As of Reaper of Souls, the Mystic can enchant an item to add a socket, assuming the following are true:

- The item can potentially have a socket (i.e. you can't enchant gloves to add a socket)
- The item has no sockets currently

If an item does have sockets, and you choose to re-roll the Sockets statistic, you could potentially add more sockets if the item can have more (i.e. a chest has 2 sockets, you could re-roll the sockets stat to potentially get a 3rd socket).

In addition, as of patch 2.1.0, you can add a socket to a weapon if you find a Ramaladni's Gift. This will only add a socket to a weapon if the weapon doesn't already have a socket.

Answer (score 2):

The artisan cannot add sockets to items but you can visit the lady the enchants your weapons and trade one of the magic properties for a socket. . Might be worth it but maybe not

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are available through the Mystic on a random basis (if the random characteristic is capable of being changed.  It can be very expensive in a variety of ways.  In addition, sockets may be added by the use of "Ramaladni's Gift".  It is a one time use item.  It is only found in the Torment levels and is only usable upon Weapons.  Those weapons may not already have sockets.

Other than weapons, one of the best uses of sockets are in legendary jewelry (rings & amulets) with legendary gems.  Legendary gems are awesome and only available in torment levels when defeating the rift guardians in the "Greater" rifts.  A set of these can easily pop you up to handle higher torment levels.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read level 9 does not do it. I have seen screenshots at level 10 without the option to add a socket. It might be a recipe that needs to be found first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no socket add in D3

This was only avalible in D2 expansion ACT5 lord of destruction

Maybe it will be avalible in the D3 expansion Reapers of soul

Answer (score -3):

To "add" sockets, you have to re-roll a statistic on a piece of armor or weapon, using the "enchant" feature at the mystic. It is random, so there is no guarantee you will get a socket as the replacement stat.

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything new.