# Does a socket count as a magical property?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I'm crafting an item which says it will have 3 magical properties does a socket (or multiple sockets) count as one of those properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, sockets count as one of the the +magical properties when crafting, [Bashiok said](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5235704764?page=2#21):

> Oh... and regardless of how many sockets you have, it only counts as a single affix. If an item rolls up 2 or 3 sockets, that still only accounts for a single affix spot on the item. ... Gem sockets, regardless of how many, only account for one of those 4 affixes

Check out [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68018/2259) for how many sockets you might be able to get.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. However, multiple sockets only count as one affix, so an item with multiple sockets can be quite a prize!