# Why are there items with absolutely no attributes?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have found 5 or 6 items now, all jewelry, that have no attributes. Just a socket and that is it. Is this a known bug, or is it just the luck of the draw? I would think an item is completely worthless without any attributes at all.

Comment: Shouldn't this be _magic items_ with no attributes - though as mentioned, sockets **is** an attribute!

Comment: Is it possible to get an amulet that is not magical?

Comment: Good point, its implied for jewelry :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a socket count as a magical property?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68932/does-a-socket-count-as-a-magical-property)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Socket *is* an attribute.

The presence of one or more sockets is considered an affix, just like +Dex or +Magic Find.

Since some blue items only have one Affix, a single socket is a valid variant of this.

Comment: What a rip off.

Comment: @Emerica. Not really. Since gems don't have a required minimum level, you can potentially socket an extremely powerful gem on a low item.

Comment: @JamesJiao On the other hand, you can find a "Requires level 52" ring with *only* a socket. (You could get the same thing at, for instance, level 17)

Comment: @RavenDreamer Yep. Not saying all of them are valuable. Was just trying to find a valid counterargument to Emerica's comment :).

Answer (score 1):

The is a socketed item (combined with the biggest stones they can be quit powerful).